# 1 Cor 12:3: "no one can say, “Jesus is Lord,” except by the Holy Spirit"

Tags: 1-corinthians

> 1 Cor 12:3 "Therefore I want you to know that no one who is speaking
>   by the Spirit of God says, “Jesus be cursed,” and no one can say,
>   “Jesus is Lord,” except by the Holy Spirit." (NIV)

Does the text in Greek contain the connotation of a second-grammatical-person address in "and no one can say, “Jesus is Lord,”"? In other words, can it be rendered like: ""and no one can say, “Jesus, Lord!” except by...", that is, "no one can address Jesus (like in prayer) by calling Him "Lord!" except by..."

Comment: The Greek original does not have a verb between 'Lord' and 'Jesus'. The literal rendering is '... no-one can say Lord Jesus ...' [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_corinthians/12-3.htm).

Comment: However note that the nouns are nominative case.  We would expect vocative case if addressing the Lord Jesus in a prayer.  On the other hand, Paul's point is about recognizing Jesus as Lord rather than noun case.  Thus, like a prayer would be included, but not exclude the other cases.

Comment: @PerryWebb - "We would expect vocative case if addressing the Lord Jesus in a prayer" - How would "Lord" be in vocative in Greek?

Comment: Vocative: Κύριε Ιησού

Comment: Eastern Orthodox: Κύριε, ἐλέησον (Lord have mercy)

Comment: @PerryWebb - What do you mean by "Eastern Orthodox" here?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my (overly) literal rendering of 1 Cor 12:3

> Wherefore, I make known to you that no-one speaking by the Spirit of
>   God says, "*A curse [on/is] Jesus*"; and no one is able to say, "*Lord
>   Jesus*" except by [the] Holy Spirit.

Thus we have two essentially independent clauses - one negative and the other positive.  Two phrases highlighted in quotes above contain only nouns in the nominative case and behave like Greek proverbs and have no verbs.  Every translation I could find correctly inserts verbs to make these overly succinct phrases intelligible in English, and so renders them something like:

"Jesus is Cursed", or, "Accursed is Jesus", or, "Jesus be cursed", etc.  The second phrase is usually rendered, "Jesus is Lord".

I also agree with Perry Webb that these two phrases cannot be part of any prayer because they lack the vocative.